# VBA code for creating a specific JSON File

Tags: json, excel, vba

Anybody create the Excel VBA code for the following json file ?

```
   "Version": "1.1",    
    "TranDtls": {   
        "TaxSch": "GST",    
        "SupTyp": "B2B",    
        "IgstOnIntra": "N", 
        "RegRev": "N",  
        "EcmGstin": null    
    },  
    "DocDtls": {    
        "Typ": "INV",   
        "No": "1",  
        "Dt": "21/10/2022"
```

Excel VBA code for the JSON file CREATION

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 1):

We need some more information to help you find the correct answer. Do you want to read/import this json string or do you want to have Excel create such a string for export?

You can use the [VBA-JSON](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) module from github. A simple way to create the string is to copy paste it into a string variable and use the Replace function;

```
sTemp = "...      "TaxSch": "[TaxSch]",....  
sJson = Replace(sTemp,"[TaxSch]", Yourvalue)
```

Or you could use concatenation but that will be more difficult with all the quotes.

Comment: I used this code -    Set objectProperties = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each c In ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).HeaderRowRange.Cells
objectProperties.Add c.Column, c.Value
Next
Dim collectionToJson As New Collection
For Each r In ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListRows
Set jsonObject = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each c In r.Range.Cells
jsonObject.Add objectProperties(c.Column), c.Value
Next
collectionToJson.Add jsonObject
Next
fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="JSON Files(*.json),*json")